# How to make a userform's property retain a value between its instance calls

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform containing controls that should keep their states. Someone in this forum taught me userforms in VBA should be treated like classes. So, how can you make it keep its values between the instance calls? I want to do proper coding and avoid global variabels. This I have been taught by another developper in this forum as well.
Here my try to make the uf keep the choice made:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Static Schalter As Boolean
Me.ToggleButton1 = Schalter

End Sub
```

Comment: The controls on users forms should not change between .hide and .show so there is no need to declare variables to preserve  the values.  This changes if you wish to implement a cancel button where the values present when the form is shown are reinstated on a cancel command.  In this case you should have a private variable for each control that can be changed and code to save and restore the values as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, so this implies any userform remains open as long as the excel project runs.

Comment: You need to read up on what happens with new userform, userform.show, userform.hide and userform.unload.

Answer (score 0):

## Public vs Static

This works. Why shouldn't it be correct?

### UserForm1

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()
  Schalter = ToggleButton1.Value
  Debug.Print "ToggleButton1 = " & Schalter
End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  Me.ToggleButton1 = Schalter
  Debug.Print "Userform Initialize Schalter = " & Schalter
End Sub
```

### Module1

```
Option Explicit
Public Schalter As Boolean
```

Comment: Yes it works, thank you! But as I wrote in the post, it was touted that proficient developers don't need any global variables.

Comment: No prob. I would like to see that solution, too. We'll just have to wait. But this could be used as a clarification of what you are asking here: To do this without the use of Module1.

Answer (score 0):

The basic issue is that you are presumably creating new instances, which will reset the values. What you actually want to do is to hold onto the instance, toggling between hidden and shown. That way, the same instance shows up with the value still remembered.

This works fine if you only need one instance, but if you need multiple instance or if you don't want to keep toting around that instance, then what you need to do is to separate the model from the view. Strictly speaking, the `Schalter` is not in any way tied to the form --- that's just the UI to manipulate the boolean, right? So treat it as a model, and provide the model to the form (aka the view), then you can easily dismiss the form instance whatever and still have the data you need. And if you decide to show the form (or maybe even a different form), you already have the model with everything set up.

That pattern will do a lot to keep your code clean and well separated. Read up on Model-View-Presenter pattern. [Here's a blog on this subject that might help](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/).

Comment: Yes thank you, I knew about the modeling distinction. But in the case of multiple instances which get destroyed in the end, Schalter inevitably ought to be global, right? Or is there another way? I wanted to use static, but this doesn't work.

Comment: No. The instance should both accept the model on creation and return a modified model. You only need to persist the model within the scope needed for that model. The scope can be longer than the individual forms used to display the data, so it's not an issue to destroy the instance since you already got the model.